# Fetching Value from Json Array Object in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm new to Postgres so I'm stuck while creating a query.

The table definition:

```
id - primary key,
data - JSON
```

Sample data:

```
id       data
--------------------------------------------------------------
1           [{"279863":"500040004","awb_no":"18171917033930"},{"279864":"500040003","awb_no":"18171917033931"}]
```

I want to find the key (279864) exists in my data column using where clause

Answer (score 1):

```
t=# with c(id,data) as (values(1,'[{"279863":"500040004","awb_no":"18171917033930"},{"279864":"500040003","awb_no":"18171917033931"}]'::json))
select id,json_object_keys(json_array_elements(data)) = '279864' from c;
 id | ?column?
----+----------
  1 | f
  1 | f
  1 | t
  1 | f
(4 rows)
```

so you can check with `WHERE EXISTS` or `count(*) > 0` or any another way you like...

eg, [with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) `bool_or` (if at least one is true, group is true):

```
t=# with c(id,data) as (values(1,'[{"279863":"500040004","awb_no":"18171917033930"},{"279864":"500040003","awb_no":"18171917033931"}]'::json))
, m as (select id,(json_object_keys(json_array_elements(data)) = '279864')j from c)
select id, bool_or(j) from m group by id;
 id | bool_or
----+---------
  1 | t
(1 row)
```

So in short:

1. use `json_array_elements` to divide array for check.
2. use `json_object_keys` toget the key of divided array element
3. use bool_or to check if at least one key is like pattern

**update** as OP is asking for "less complicated" solution, I post a monkey hack as well:

```
t=# with c(id,data) as (values(1,'[{"279863":"500040004","awb_no":"18171917033930"},{"279864":"500040003","awb_no":"18171917033931"}]'::json))
select * from c where data::jsonb::text ~ '(,)|({ )"279863":';
 id |                                                data
----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | [{"279863":"500040004","awb_no":"18171917033930"},{"279864":"500040003","awb_no":"18171917033931"}]
(1 row)
```

which is of course is very slippery and requires some explanation as well:

1. I need to cast to `jsonb` first to eliminate possible syntax freedom
2. json object keys are not sorted, thus I need to catch both `{`{ and `,` cases

Comment: any other way to handle this?

Comment: currently, my query already working with joins and group by and it was already complicated. So is there any other way to handle it.

Comment: ah, I see. no - fetching array elements requires unnesting the array, which will require grouping after the check - other way is quite a monkey hack - I'll post it as alternative

Answer (score 0):

make data column as `JSONB` and then you can easily do by using:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data->>'279863' IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I cannot change this value bcoz it's my live application, any other way to get this data?